# Configuration API unable to access xml files

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce, bigdata

I created a xml files named `Config.xml`. Below is the content:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
    <property>
        <name>
            color
        </name>
        <value>
            yellow
        </value>
        <description>
            Color
        </description>
    </property>
</configuration>
```

I tried to access this xml file using the below code:

```
    Configuration conf = new Configuration();
    conf.addResource("/Users/XXX/Documents/Config.xml");
    System.out.println(conf.get("color"));
```

`null` is getting printed in the console. Please advice.

Comment: Checked in the source code: Configuration does call trim on the value of the `<name>` element.

Comment: Any specific reasons for why this is not working? Please suggest.